# Cannot display MySQL latin2_croation_ci characters in Python script

Tags: python, mysql, character-encoding

I am trying to apply MySQL records in a Python script.  The fields I am concerned with use latin2_croatian_ci collation characters.  When I try to print out the following characters,

```
Karadžić
Stanišić & Simatović
Boškoski & Tarčulovski
Đorđević
Ražnatović, Željko
```

I get only,

```
Karadži?
Staniši? & Simatovi?
Boškoski & Tar?ulovski
?or?evi?
Ražnatovi?, Željko
```

I have tried numerous strategies from both MySQL and Python.  In MySQL I have tried both CONVERT and CAST in various combinations.  In Python I have tried applying the unicode() function.  Nothing seems to work.  In Flash, I had to set the embedding to "latin extended A" to solve a similar problem.

Any and all tips and or clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line as second line into your python script (after `#!/usr/bin/python`)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

with `utf-8` you should be ok